# Why is my window losing its HTMEME when I call SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_STYLE) on it?

Tags: c++, winapi, themes, gdi, uxtheme

I'm coding a custom Win32 UI control that I want to incorporate visual themes in. I load themes in its `WM_NCCREATE` as such:

```
case WM_NCCREATE:
{
    HTHEME hTheme = ::OpenThemeData(hWnd, L"EDIT");
    assert(hTheme);
    assert(::GetWindowTheme(hWnd) != 0);

}
return 1;
```

and then release them when control is destroyed:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    HTHEME hTheme = ::GetWindowTheme(hWnd);
    assert(hTheme);
    if(::CloseThemeData(hTheme) != S_OK)
    {
        assert(NULL);
    }
}
break;
```

This works well, until someone tries to change that control's styles. The following call (just by itself without even changing any styles):

```
::SetWindowLongPtr(hChildWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
```

will make `GetWindowTheme` on `hChildWnd` return NULL.

So, *is it a bug or a feature*?

PS. To make a reproducible Win32 example I had to adjust the stock Win32 solution from the VS 2017. ([Here](https://mega.nz/#!uXpkRAAS!jvqYAn3RY1fWWREduXwQDJ03InN7IARQeEFykAzfVss) is its full source code.) The way it works is this: in it I create a small child control (shown in gray below) that has theme in question:

[image]

Then when you click on the white area of the main window, I try to change its styles and its theme disappears:

[image]

To see the full Win32 code for that project, I also [posted it on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/eyRBmU0f).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No, it's supposed to be `GetWindowTheme` and no, there's no handle leak there. It's removed in `WM_DESTROY`. That first assertion shows that the window actually had that theme handle. As for your last point, if I follow your logic, why would I "trust" the HWND to store `WNDCLASSEXW::cbWndExtra` data or window styles, or anything else either?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's not the point. `GetWindowTheme` is used in many places to store theme handle. Again, my question is why does `SetWindowLongPtr` seem to reset it?

Comment: Just like with any other handle type, your WM_NCCREATE should save the opened HTHEME somewhere for WM_DESTROY to close later, don't rely on the HWND remembering the HTHEME for you. And don't forget to handle WM_THEMECHANGED, too.

Comment: you need save result of `OpenThemeData` in struct accosiated with window and use saved value in call `CloseThemeData`. use `GetWindowTheme` no sense at all, it only returns the **most recent** theme handle from `OpenThemeData`. if another code internally call `OpenThemeData` result will be another already. not reliable api at all

Comment: @RbMm: `GetWindowTheme` seems to [be used](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/comctl32/edit.c) for that kinda purpose.

Comment: `GetWindowTheme` simply returns the most recent theme handle from `OpenThemeData`. use `OpenThemeData` **once** for open need to you threme. if you open threme - **save** returned handle in class data. also you probably need to call `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"Explorer", 0);`

Comment: @c00000fd `OpenThemeData()` can be called multiple times on a window, and `GetWindowTheme()` will return only the last opened theme. Each opened HTHEME needs to be closed individually. The safest option is to remember the HTHEME you open so you can close it. Don't expect `GetWindowTheme()` to always return the same HTHEME you opened

Comment: @RemyLebeau: OK, I see that. I guess it's a bug in Wine then.

Comment: @c00000fd "*I guess it's a bug **in Wine** then.*" - the fact that you are not even running your app on a *real* Windows system but in an *emulated* system is a very important piece of information that you should have provided up front.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28VS.85%29.aspx) document:

> "After the window has been created, these styles cannot be modified,
>   except as noted."

Because this is not permitted, the theme engine does not always check for changed styles and in some circumstances will draw the caption based on old data. And the only guaranteed and supportable solution is for the application to destroy the window and recreate it with the new styles rather than trying to change them on the fly.

A similar discussion can be found:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/7b5ef777-ff0d-4f15-afed-5588f93f0e23